# Phoenix templates if conditional

Tags: phoenix-framework

Im migrating from rails, and expected this to work, in my template?

```
      <% if true do %>
        <li><p>hello</p></li>
      <% else %>
        <li><p>world</p></li>
      <% end %>
```

None of the condition seem to get rendered. How to acheive this?

Thank you

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to use `<%=` instead of `<%`

```
<%= if true do %>
...
<% end %>
```

From the [EEx docs](https://hexdocs.pm/eex/EEx.html):

> All expressions that output something to the template must use the equals sign (=). Since everything in Elixir is an expression, there are no exceptions for this rule. For example, while some template languages would special-case if clauses, they are treated the same in EEx and also require = in order to have their result printed:

Comment: so I'm struggling with why the `end` doesn't require the equal sign? I've got one that has an `else` in it, and there is output to the template in that, so why doesn't it need the =?

Comment: Because the expression that has a value is the `if`, not the `end`. The `end` is part of the `if` syntax.

Comment: `<div class={"flex #{if @is_home, do: 'home'}"}>` for inline conditionals (for example for class names) inside elixir templates, maybe this will be helpful to someone